# Hudson: updating config.xml for currently running job, and make running job immediately aware of updated config.xml

Tags: java, hudson

I have a situation where my hudson server is currently running a build and a new config.xml needs to be updated to the currently running build. How can this be achieved ?

Secondly, once the new config.xml is POSTed, how can I make the currently running build to be aware of the new config.xml and continue build ?

For example, following config.xml specifies to run

```
java -cp Test.jar argument1
```

Build commences and is running.

A new config.xml is POSTed to the currently running job.

```
java -cp Test.jar newargument1
```

How can I make Test.jar aware of the newargument1 that has been updated in the config.xml file ?

Essentially, I am trying to avoid having to start a new build again from scratch with the new config.xml update.

Answer (score 1):

let's assume the first config.xml file is called file1 and the second config.xml file is called file2.

why would you change the file1 to file2 in the middle of the build?
either there has to be a reason (henece a condition) which you would be able to implement 
it either using a powershell or a Bash script

-or-

there is not a specific reason and in that case you can just appened (not literally) the file2 to file1 meaning combine the two xml files and let the build run from start to finish.

in order to post an xml on top of another xml, meaning file2 on top of file1 then post your xml to the below URL:

```
http://<HUDSON_URL>/job/<JOB_NAME>/config.xml
```

however, this will not be effective while the build is running. it only be executed after the job is stopped and/or finished running file1.

if you are using curl, make sure to use the --data-binary option to send the config.xml (file2) to the hudson server.

Answer (score 0):

You have no chance to do that using Hudson's features. You need to cancel the build and restart it.

That said, there is an ugly workaround. You need to read the parameter from file. This way, you can change the file. When the job is at the point of reading the file, it will get the most current parameter. Unfortunately, every single build step needs to read the parameters from file, since there is no way to pass data from one build step to another. If you have only one build step, then this solution is useless. So in essence you need to make your build itself aware of the changes.

I see the danger here that you get screwy (non reproducible) results, when changing some build parameters halfway through the execution. So my recommendation is to cancel and restart.

May be there are other solutions for your problem. Can you explain the big picture? Why do you want to avoid a restart? Does the checkout takes that long?